# Get File or Folder from git commit hash

Tags: git, terminal, command-line-interface

So let's say I have a hash `ccf52ef35d7767c5b0f251542ab79608c50a3a56`.

How do I use the `git` command line to get the contents of the file from the commit hash and file structure.

Also, how do I get a directory listing if the path is a directory, not a file. I do not need checking, just the two commands you would use for each.

I know this is the command:
`git log [<options>] [<since>..<until>] [[--] <path>...]` and [here is the page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-log).

I tried `git log ccf52ef35d7767c5b0f251542ab79608c50a3a56`, but that just returned the generic `git log` (all commits). I don't even know how I would get the contents of the file, except for maybe piping it into an `ls` or `cat`.

Edit: Okay so I figured out `git show --pretty="format:" --name-only a3da8bb`. Is the best way to just grep out either a directory and cat the file from there? Edit 2: Saw the answer, thanks. Still looking to figure out how to `cat` a file.

Comment: A commit hash isn't unique for a single file, it's unique for a whole commit which can consist of multiple files.

Comment: Yes, I know. I'll have the directory structure and file name already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want:

```
git show --pretty="format:" --name-only <sha1 hash>
```

It will show the files added / modified / deleted in the commit. Instead of `--name-only`, you can use `--name-status` to show the names along with the status ( modifed, added..)

To get the contents of file, you can use:

```
git show <hash>:file
```

or

```
git cat-file -p <hash>:file
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Pretty simple, in fact.

`git show hash:path/to/file`